# Catacombs: Chain Shot Modifier and misses

Tags: catacombs

As per the rules of Catacombs 3rd Ed.:

> The *chain shot modifier* indicates tha the same target cannot be damaged consecutively in a shot sequence [...]. If the same target is hit twice consecutively, damage that would have been inflicted by the second hit is ignored.

Does a miss in a shot sequence count as a "change of target" (can't find a better wording)?

Let's say Xoric the Barbarian plays the *Berserker Battle Axe* Item card:

> (Melee) > (Melee) > (Melee) > (Melee)

Xoric uses the first (Melee) to hit a Minotaur (flipping it over) then aim a Zombie with his second one but misses it. Can he use his third (Melee) to kill the Minotaur he hit in the first shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is slightly ambiguous, the "consecutively" refers to shots taken in the sequence. If you hit A on shot 1 in a sequence, you won't be able to damage A on shot 2 no matter what, but shot 3 is fine.

If I hit A on my first shot, then on my second shot hit B then A, A would still only take the one damage (despite the "change of target").

This limit isn't to force you to change targets but to encourage it, and to limit the damage a sequence can do to a single target. This way the Overseer can't take a boss sequence and just eliminate a single player trivially, and the Barbarian can't use items to take down the boss in two turns.